# How to write a query to filter a table according to a range of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns `call_no`, `status`, and `sub_staus`

For ex: records are like this.

```
call_no  status  sub_staus
123      2       null
123      79      null
123      null    119 
231      5       null
231      null    78
```

I need to fetch a `call_no` whose status is **79** and sub_status is **119**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Questions that requests a solution without showing your effort and research are not recommended, include what have you tried, what did you face while trying to reach your desired output. and if you didn't find this issue solved else where, post a good formatted question to receive a quick and clean answer, and maybe up-votes on your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using aggregation and `having`:

```
select call_no
from t
group by call_no
having sum(case when status = 79 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when sub_status = 119 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CALL_NO
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CALL_NO
HAVING SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN STATUS = 79
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) > 0
AND SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN SUB_STATUS = 119
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) > 0;
```

Comment: why offer a solution that has already been provided (ignoring format differences)?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want maximum values - but this is a guess. If you want calls that **have had** status 79 and sub-status 119 then using SUM(case....) would apply, but using maximums may give you calls that **are currently** at status 79 and sub-status 119.

```
select call_no
from t
group by call_no
having max(status) = 79
   and max(sub_status) = 119;
```